# Scala generic "string split" method

Tags: scala, scala-collections

If I were splitting a string, I would be able to do

```
"123,456,789".split(",")
```

to get 
`Seq("123","456","789")`

Thinking of a string as a sequence of characters, how could this be generalized to other sequences of objects?

```
val x = Seq(One(),Two(),Three(),Comma(),Five(),Six(),Comma(),Seven(),Eight(),Nine())
x.split(
  number=>{
    case _:Comma => true
    case _ => false
  }
)
```

split in this case doesn't exist, but it reminds me of span, partition, groupby, but only span seems close, but it doesn't handle leading/ending comma's gracefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```scala
implicit class SplitSeq[T](seq: Seq[T]){
  import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
  def split(sep: T): Seq[Seq[T]] = {
    val buffer = ListBuffer(ListBuffer.empty[T])
    seq.foreach {
      case `sep` => buffer += ListBuffer.empty
      case elem => buffer.last += elem
    }; buffer.filter(_.nonEmpty)
  }
}
```

It can be then used like `x.split(Comma())`.

Comment: Accepted this over Meghana's as it seems more readable to me + it doesn't need multiple tuple2 creation.

Answer (score 1):

The following is 'a' solution, not the most elegant -

```
def split[A](x: Seq[A], edge: A => Boolean): Seq[Seq[A]] = { 

  val init = (Seq[Seq[A]](), Seq[A]())

  val (result, last) = x.foldLeft(init) { (cum, n) =>
    val (total, prev) = cum

    if (edge(n)) {
        (total :+ prev, Seq.empty)
    } else {
        (total, prev :+ n)
    }
  }

  result :+ last
}
```

Example result -

```
scala> split(Seq(1,2,3,0,4,5,0,6,7), (_:Int) == 0)
res53: Seq[Seq[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5), List(6, 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've solved it in the past, but I suspect there is a better / more elegant way.

```
  def break[A](xs:Seq[A], p:A => Boolean): (Seq[A], Seq[A]) = {
    if (p(xs.head)) {
      xs.span(p)
    }
    else {
      xs.span(a => !p(a))
    }
  }
```